# How to prevent Material-UI ThemeProvider being applied to a specific child in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm working on a ReactJS project where some of the components are wrapped with `<ThemeProvider>` of Material-UI. Due to this, any children of the component with ThemeProvider are breaking when styled with `makeStyle()`.
For example, I have a material-table wrapped with ThemeProvider and a custom component rendered like this:

```
...
<ThemeProvider theme={tableTheme}>
   <MaterialTable
      title="Render Image Preview"
      columns={[
        { title: 'Something', field: 'someData', render: rowData => <MyMaterialUIComponent> },
      ...
   />
<ThemeProvider>
...
```

MyMaterialUIComponent is styled with makeStyle() of material-ui, however, if there exists a style field that was not overridden in makeStyle(), then tableTheme gets applied to it.
I don't have the requirement of overriding all style fields if I don't do that tableTheme will get applied.

**I can't just let the tableTheme get applied to it as  will be rendered as a child of MaterialTable as well as out side the MaterialTable, hence the same component looks different when different parents call it.**

How can I prevent ThemeProvider from applying theme MyMaterialUIComponent when rendered as a child of Material-Table ?

Comment: You could wrap that in an additional Theme provider with the desired theme

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm doing it right now. But we are avoiding Theme Provider considering the complexity associated with that. Further, I personally feel it's not the correct way to create another theme just to prevent a theme from getting applied.